What's the difference between Arabic prosody and English rhythm?
I don't understand English rhythm and its law; and see English poems and still nothing. However some poets like Edward Fitzgerald have poems based on Persian (Arabic) prosody and I get its rhythm but for others I can't. What the laws of English rhythm?

I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about writing. And if it is, the scope of this question is too vast for this site. Metre is a complex and complicated topic. There is a Wikipedia article that explains the basics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry). There are books and articles about metre. Get one.

agree. it's fascinating and on-topic, but way out of scope.

This question would be a better fit on LitSE.
